# PHP cURL webscrape.. I ran into some issue. It return me blank page. When I tried to get the Specific content

Tags: php, html, curl, web-scraping, web-crawler

PHP cURL webscrape.. I ran into some issue. It return me blank page. When I tried to get the Specific content..

For example..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
       <td>test1</td>
       <td>test1</td>
       <td>test1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

I only need the content of `<tr></tr>`

here is my code snippet.

```
// Defining the basic cURL function
function curl($url) {
    // Assigning cURL options to an array
    $options = Array(
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        // CURLOPT_CAINFO => 'cacert.pem',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,  // Setting cURL's option to return the webpage data
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,  // Setting cURL to follow 'location' HTTP headers
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE, // Automatically set the referer where following 'location' HTTP headers
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,   // Setting the amount of time (in seconds) before the request times out
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,  // Setting the maximum amount of time for cURL to execute queries
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, // Setting the maximum number of redirections to follow
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8",  // Setting the useragent
        CURLOPT_URL => $url, // Setting cURL's URL option with the $url variable passed into the function
    );

    $ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL 
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);   // Setting cURL's options using the previously assigned array data in $options
    $data = curl_exec($ch); // Executing the cURL request and assigning the returned data to the $data variable
    curl_close($ch);    // Closing cURL 
    return $data;   // Returning the data from the function 
}




// Defining the basic scraping function
function scrape_between($data, $start, $end){
    $data = stristr($data, $start); // Stripping all data from before $start
    $data = substr($data, strlen($start));  // Stripping $start
    $stop = stripos($data, $end);   // Getting the position of the $end of the data to scrape
    $data = substr($data, 0, $stop);    // Stripping all data from after and including the $end of the data to scrape
    return $data;   // Returning the scraped data from the function
}



$url = "https://www.weddingwire.com/c/ak-alaska/wedding-officiants/9-sca.html";      

$results_page = curl($url); // Downloading the results page using our curl() funtion

$results_page = scrape_between($results_page, '<div class="js-search-results">', '<div class="col-xs-12 testing-catalog-pagination-links">'); // Scraping out only the middle section of the results page that contains our results
```

[Data That I need to parsed!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taMjr.png)

Here is the source code that i must give credits.. 
http://www.jacobward.co.uk/web-scraping-with-php-curl-part-1/

Comment: How should we help with that, without knowing the data you are trying to break apart?

Comment: i have updated my concern. Please check it. I hope you can help me more..

Comment: There is not really much of a connection between the example data you provide, the screenshot you added and the actual search criteria you implemented. That is why I gave a more general answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Using plain string functions is a somewhat ineffective approach to parsing markup data. Regular expressions offer more flexibility, but solutions based on them typically have little robustness against minor changes to the markup structure.

Best is to use a DOM parser. They are the right tool, specifically crafted for such task. You throw the markup into the parser object, then you can "browse" the structure and select and extract whatever data you need in there.

Take a look at this simple example:

```
<?php
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$markup = <<<EOT
<html>
  <body>
    <div>foo 1</div>
    <div class="category-landing-links">
      <div class="col-xs-4">bla 1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">bla 2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">bla 3</div>
    </div>
    <div>foo 2</div>
  </body>
</html>
EOT;

$htmlDom = str_get_html($markup);
$outerDivs = $htmlDom->find('div[class=category-landing-links]');

$finalData = [];
foreach ($outerDivs as $key=>$outerDiv) {
  foreach ($outerDiv->children() as $innerDiv) {
    $finalData[$key][] = $innerDiv->innertext;
  }
}
var_dump($finalData);
```

The output of the above is:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(5) "bla 1"
    [1] =>
    string(5) "bla 2"
    [2] =>
    string(5) "bla 3"
  }
}
```

So an array holding an entry for each matched outer `<div>` tag which in turn hold  the inner text of all children `<div>` tags. You will probably have to adapt it to your needs, depending on the specific situation.

[`simple_html_dom.php`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is the implementation of a very simple DOM parser. It is a bit older, but works perfectly fine. It is free software that is offered on SourceForge. The online documentation offers examples that are easy to understand and demonstrate most features.

Comment: I tried that one. And got the answer right. I`m using cURL because someone tells me that cURL is faster.. 

Using simple_html_dom make my request error 504 Timeout. And i think it was an execution timeout set by the server. How can i fix this. Or any suggestion in muliple link using simple_html_dom with pagination?

Comment: for multiple links. Im using nested foreach loop every links and pagination. But when i got my 9th data in link1->link2->data content.. the page give me an error of 504..

Comment: The question of speed in a http request is decided by the slowest component, which is the request itself, not the client side implementation.

Comment: `cURL` certainly gives you more freedom to shape the request the way you want it.

Comment: That timeout issue reads as if your own script times out. That is to be expected if you try to do batch processing sequentially in a web based php script. That never is a good idea. Take a look at job queuing systems instead which allow you to process those scraping jobs one by one in a batch manner.

Comment: Can you give me some links or idea about job queuing system when parsing or scraping a data..

Comment: The scraping or parsing is independent of the job queuing. Job queuing systems are a general approach, just google for it. Each job you process that way scrapes exactly one URL, maybe even only one page, depends, actually.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+job+queuing+system&oq=php+job+queuing+system&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i64.3863j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8